# MySQLdb - OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Tags: mysql, macos, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have the below script working on my Macbook pro, all executes correctly and inserts data into the database. I have just done a fresh install on my work iMac with the same python version and same modules installed, but the new installed iMac gives an error.

Here is the code:

```
import MySQLdb
import traceback

databaseName = "dbName"
tableName = "tableName"
databaseLocation = "10.0.1.1"
databaseUsername = "uname"
databasePassword = "pass"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=databaseLocation,
                    user=databaseUsername,
                    passwd=databasePassword,
                    db=databaseName,
                    use_unicode=1,
                    charset="utf8")

try:
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT count(*) as tot FROM %s" % tableName)
except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT count(*) as tot FROM %s" % tableName)

insert = "insert into {} (title, vendorID, partnerName, packageFormat, packageType, jobStepID, status, percentage, platform, submittedBy, submitTime, portalResponce, totalFiles, completeTime) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)".format(tableName)
try:
    cur.execute(insert, ("test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"))
    db.commit()

except Exception:
    print (traceback.format_exc())
    db.rollback()
cur.close()
```

And here is the error I am getting on the new install:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

Here is the table it is inserting into:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| JobID          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vendorID       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| partnerName    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| packageFormat  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| packageType    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| jobStepID      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| percentage     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| platform       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| submittedBy    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| submitTime     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| portalResponce | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totalFiles     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| completeTime   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As far as I can see everything matches, very weird as on one Mac the script works and on the new install iMac it does not. Is there something I am completely overlooking?

Comment: Are you attempting to insert into the same database instance from both machines? If not, have you verified that the details of the table are identical?

Comment: yes same db, same table...